# Broken links in tag subscription email

Tags: discussion, email-notification, 404-not-found, subscription

I have subscribed questions of certain tags. It sends me email whenever a question is asked under the tag. But recently I am getting lot of `Page Not Found`. When I click link on the email, it shows `Page Not Found`. I know the question might have been closed after sending the subscription email. How can we prevent this and ensure quality of subscription emails?

**Suggestion:**

Include questions in subscription email only if it meets certain standards like zero close votes, non negative vote etc.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just gave excellent **counter-example** to what you suggest.

[The question you mention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30379676/php-exec-command-collect2-cannot-find-ld) has been deleted, by its owner, 9 hours ago:

> [image]

- It was deleted after the email was sent
- It did not have a single close vote
- It did not have a single down vote

If you expect Stack Exchange to magically change the email in your inbox when a question is deleted, I fear that's not (yet?) technically possible.

Comment: Sorry. I could see only that 404 page.

Comment: @Harikrishnan it clearly says "This question was voluntarily removed by its author" in the 404 error page.

Comment: Ya. That's right. I didn't pay enough attention on that.

Comment: Maybe not technical possible but if you do some wizardry...

Comment: It's Stack Exchange's second most important secret internal project. The #1 is the invention of the mind reading device that so many posters think we already have.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Is it possible to embed an iframe like device in an email?

Comment: @Tim interesting idea, however [link1](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3219/do-iframes-work-in-email/) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976966/how-to-display-iframe-tag-to-gmail) bring us to the conclusion it won't do any good. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard looks like we want this: http://www.google.com/patents/US7568010